# Is there a diagram of the category of sets?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

If the category of sets is structurally defined by all functions between all sets, is there any way to diagrammatically see even a part of this category? Is there a more abstract way where functions would be grouped into classes, so the overall structure of the category could be viewed?

Comment: Even a diagram of all maps from a 3-element set to itself is pretty messy.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually trying to find a comprehensive way to discover all possible mappings that can produce a particular set. I wonder if a computer could generate the category of sets, then identify all sequences of arrows (starting from any object) which result in the same resulting object? Since it would need to be made finite, maybe the question can be explored by increment the maximum size of any set in the category.